# How to apply potion effect to players in specific distance?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make my friend Bee get the weakness potion effect every time she goes 20 blocks near my other friend Kay.

How do I do this with command blocks?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the wiki:

```
execute @a[name=Kay] ~ ~ ~ execute @a[name=Bee,rm=0,r=20] ~ ~ ~ effect @s weakness <time> <amplifier>
```

Which translates to:

```
Execute at Kay, as Bee if closer then 20 blocks (inclusive), give them (Bee) an effect
```